# Getting Python import error for a package within my project

Tags: python, import

I am hoping someone could shine some light on a really odd situation I am running into today. I have a project I completed that runs great in PyCharm; however, when trying to call the project from the command line, this is the error I am receiving:

```
[root@vodgsnxf-po-a2p ~]# python /opt/gsnworkflow/GSNEventLoop/EventLoop.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/gsnworkflow/GSNEventLoop/EventLoop.py", line 6, in <module>
   from Modules import FileOperations
ImportError: No module named Modules
```

Here is my file layout:

```
/opt/gsnworkflow/
|-- __init__.py  
|-- GSNEventLoop/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- EventLoop.py
`-- Modules/
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- Configuration.py
    |-- Logging.py
    |-- FileOperations.py
    `-- Database.py
```

I have tried a bunch of different `sys.path.append` commands, such as the following:

```
sys.path.append('/opt/gsnworkflow/')  
sys.path.append('/opt/gsnworkflow/Modules/')  
sys.path.append('/opt/gsnworkflow/GSNEventLoop/')
```

None of these options have resolved my issue at all and I am getting to my wit's end. Does anyone see anything glaringly obvious that I may have missed or done incorrectly? I truly appreciate anyone who can figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: If you use python 3 try using dot syntax to call parent module : " from ..Modules import FilesOperations"

Comment: I tried that and I am getting the same results. (I am using python3). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is call module Modules from GSNEventLoop.
You need to go module **up** and then call Modules.

This is how it is done in python 3:

```
from ..Modules import FilesOperations
```

[Further reading](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html) and look for Intra-package References

About how is it done in python 2 see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Comment: I am not getting the following error after trying that:    

[root@vodgsnxf-po-a2p gsnworkflow]# python ./GSNEventLoop/EventLoop.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./GSNEventLoop/EventLoop.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ..Modules import FileOperations
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Comment: I am not sure why this is being so difficult...Never had any trouble like this before.

Comment: @AnthonyHopkins Why are you a) root and b) attempting to call EventLoop.py directly instead of going through it's package?

Comment: @Rishav I am root because the files I am working on are root-only accessible sensitive data, so they decided to lock files down to root access.....Guess they have never heard of a service account. The environment itself is sanitary and has no access to the internet and I am the only dev that has access to the server. Just makes sense in this scenario. If I FUBAR the box, then it's on me. As for your second question, I realized what I did wrong after looking over everything again but before I read your comment, which , ultimately, would have been my golden ticket had I seen it before.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. My main function existed within the GSNEventLoop directory. I moved it out and to the root of the Python package and voila. All imports work as expected. So now, My structure looks like this:

- /opt/gsnworkflow/

  - __init__.py
  - /GSNEventLoop/

    - __init__.py
    - EventLoop.py
  - /Modules/

    - __init__.py
    - Configuration.py
    - Logging.py
    - FileOperations.py
    - Database.py
  - GSNMain.py   <-- This guy contains code that executed that calls the event loop.

Once I established the GSNMain.py file, all imports and functionality works as expected. Thanks to those who reached out early and quickly to try to provide support for this. I love StackOverflow.